# How to make a repo and include few other repo in it?

Tags: git, github, repository

I am not very good at describing but I will give my best.

I am trying to work on a open source game, however it's dependencies are in few other repositories.

I want to actually create my own repo and include everything in it. What will be the best way to do it?

I have seen several other questions like this but I couldn't figure out from those.

The link to the open source game : https://github.com/MetatransApps/Android_APK_2DBalloons

Comment: You have to rely on git submodules.